# Problema com controle customizado

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, binding, componentes

Eu criei uma search bar customizada com um entry. Eu preciso pegar o text desse entry para ser um parametro de pesquisa.

Então, criei uma propriedade customizada que usa a propriedade Text do entry. Porém essa propriedade customizada não pega o texto da search bar customizada.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Abaixo deixo os códigos do controle customizado.

Código do evento click do botão de procura da search bar customizada.

```
    private async void SbcPesquisar_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string busca = SbcPesquisar.TextSearch;
            List<Promocao> Promocoes = await PromocaoService.GetListaPromocoes(busca);
            LstPromocoes.ItemsSource = Promocoes;
        }
```

Code Bihind do Controle

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
namespace MeDeiBem.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SearchBarCustom : ContentView
    {
        public event EventHandler ClickScope;
        public SearchBarCustom ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextSearchProperty = 
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "TextSearch",
                returnType: typeof(string),
                declaringType: typeof(SearchBarCustom),
                defaultValue: "",
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged: TextSearchPropertyChanged
            );

        public string TextSearch
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextSearchProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextSearchProperty, value); }
        }
        private static void TextSearchPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var searchBarCustom = (SearchBarCustom)bindable;
            searchBarCustom.textSearch.Text = (string)newValue;
        }
        private void On_clickScope(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ClickScope != null)
            {
                ClickScope(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Código XAML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MeDeiBem.FontsAwesome;assembly=MeDeiBem"
             x:Class="MeDeiBem.Controls.SearchBarCustom">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Padding="2" BorderColor="#49c1ff" CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="60">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Entry x:Name="textSearch"
                       Placeholder="Digite o que procura"                       
                       PlaceholderColor="Black"
                       FontSize="Medium"                       
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       />

                <Button Text="{x:Static local:Fontes.FASearch}" 
                        FontSize="30"                          
                        BorderWidth="0"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        WidthRequest="60" 
                        HorizontalOptions="End" 
                        Clicked="On_clickScope" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Código XAML de onde estou usando o componente:

```
<controls:SearchBarCustom x:Name="SbcPesquisar" ClickScope="SbcPesquisar_OnClicked" />
```

Comment: Olá, coloquei o código na pergunta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que faltou foi vocÊ usar a `BindableProperty` `TextSearchProperty` que você criou no seu componente. Ela já está exposta para Bindings.

Então você deverá ter uma propriedade na sua `ViewModel`, como `SearchText`, por exemplo, e usá-la com o binding no componente. Assim:

```
<controls:SearchBarCustom x:Name="SbcPesquisar" 
                          TextSearch="{Binding SearchText}"
                          ClickScope="SbcPesquisar_OnClicked" />
```

Isso porque no seu delegate `propertyChanged` definido na `BindableProperty`você fez refletir a alteração da propriedade `TextSearch` no componente `Entry` interno, mas quando a alterção ocorre no `Entry` a sua propriedade `TextSearch` não está sendo 'notificada'.

**Edit:**

Sem usar `Bindings` (como é o caso do MVVM), expor a propriedade como bindable acaba se tornando desnecessário, pois foi justamente para isso que ela foi projetada.
Mas, com alguns pequenos ajustes é possível resolver o problema que você está enfrentado.

Você vai precisar acrescentar uma propriedade `x:Name` no seu componente, definir que ele será seu proprio `BindingContext` e vincular o texto do seu `Entry` à propriedade que você expôs no codebehind do componente. Assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView ...
             x:Class="MeDeiBem.Controls.SearchBarCustom"
             x:Name="searchBarCustom">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" 
               BindingContext="{Reference searchBarCustom}"
               ...>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                         BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Entry x:Name="textSearch"
                       Text="{Binding TextSearch}"
                       Placeholder="Digite o que procura"                       
                       .../>

                <Button ... />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

<sup>** Onde tem os "..." é para você manter o seu código do jeito que está atualmente*</sup>

Esse pequeno ajuste fará com que as alterações no `Entry` reflitam na propriedade `TextSearch` e *vice-versa*. Agora você pode remover a implementação do `propertyChanged: TextSearchPropertyChanged` que você usou na `BindableProperty`.

Fazendo assim você será capaz de recuperar o conteúdo da propriedade como estava tentando:

```
private async void SbcPesquisar_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string busca = SbcPesquisar.TextSearch;
    List<Promocao> Promocoes = await PromocaoService.GetListaPromocoes(busca);
    LstPromocoes.ItemsSource = Promocoes;
}
```

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Ola  Diego. O problema é que eu não estou usando MVVM, então não tenho uma viewmodel.

Comment: Poderia me explica porque não faz sentido? Pretendo usar MVVM nos meus projetos futuros. Fiquei um pouco afastado do Xamarin e ainda estou meio perdido. Mas quero entender melhor como funciona o MVVM quando estiver com mais tempo.

Comment: @MarcosAurelio editei a resposta. Assim vai funcionar para você. Desse jeito que propus no final será desnecessário ter a implementação do `TextSearchPropertyChanged`, pode descartá-la.

Comment: Diego, fiz como voce falou, mas no XAML da erro no Reference: A propriedade searchBarCustom não foi econtrada no tipo Reference Extension. O código esta exatamente como voce fez, dei um nome ao meu componente de searchBarCustom, coloquei dentro da tag ContentView.BindingContext.

Comment: Foi falha minha, escrevi de cabeça. O `Referece` não é para ser usado como eu tinha feito. Já corrigi. Tenta agora

Comment: Diego funcionou. Tive que te agradecer. Obrigado.